# Why is an infinitely long polynomial not continuous

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, polynomials, continuity

in my multivariable class we are learning about continuous functions. We have a problem on polynomials. First we proved that monomials are continuous by proving f(x)=ax is continuous and g(x)=x is continuous and the product of f(x) with an n-1 number of g(x) makes h(x)=ax^n a continuous function. We use that to prove that polynomials are continuous because the sum of continuous functions makes a continuous function.

The next part I do not understand. They ask us to prove why an infinitely long series of monomials is not continuous by giving an example of one that is not continuous and stating why it is that we cannot apply the rules of continuous functions an infinite number of times.

can somebody help explain to me why this is? (sorry for not using a function generator, I don't have enough reputation to place images in posts because this is my first post.)

Comment: What is an "infinitely long series of monomials"?

Comment: Incidentally, such infinitely long series can fail to be continuous even at points where they are well-defined.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example in one variable. Consider the expression $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i$. You may know that this geometric series has the summation formula $\tilde{f}(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$ when $|x| < 1$. That function is discontinuous at $1$ though, and you can see that that sum does not even make sense at $1$, as if it did, it would be $1+ 1 + 1 + .... $ which is clearly not something you can evaluate to any real number.

Answer (score 1):

This question raises an important point! First, sure, while every polynomial gives a continuous function on the whole real line (or on the complex plane), *limits* (pointwise, for example) do not necessarily do so.

Nevertheless, power series (especially as functions of a complex variable) have a very intelligible behavior. Abel and others (about 200 years ago) proved that limits-of-polynomials, that is, power series, converge on the largest disk (in the complex plane) in which the associated function is complex-differentiable. On that disk, the finite partial sums of the infinite power series, polynomials, converge *uniformly* *pointwise* to the limit...

Many more things can be said! :)